# Avalondock - header for floating window

Tags: wpf, avalondock

I am using avalondock to manage tabbed documents in my wpf application.

I'm using a DocumentHeaderTemplate to style the LayoutDocument tab appearance as follows.

```
            <xcad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                            <!--<TextBlock> - This Works</TextBlock>-->
                    </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </xcad:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
```

That works great and looks nice.

When the user drags the window out of the dock to create a floating window, the header on that window is small and cuts off text.

[image: The Cut off header]

I can't seem to find the xaml to make the header bigger (on a floating window) so that I can see my text.

I have tried:  AnchorablePaneTemplate, AnchorableTitleTemplate and AnchorableHeaderTemplate...   I can't get anything to show in my header when I use those.

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a Pane Style Selector ?

Comment: Go with this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/719143/AvalonDock-Tutorial-Part-Load-Save-Layout)